# Nginx: "HTTP error before end of send"

Tags: nginx, flask

I have a Flask app with a web service returning

```
Response(json.dumps({"msg": "Access denied"}), status=403, mimetype='application/json')
```

when the request is not authenticated (basic http auth).

When running the app using Flask's development server, I don't specify any user in my request (no -u option) I get, as expected

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:5000/api/get_predictions
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> POST /api/get_predictions HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:5000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 964812
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------5a6165ae33f0142f
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 403 FORBIDDEN
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 24
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Authentication Required"
* Server Werkzeug/0.11.3 Python/2.7.11 is not blacklisted
< Server: Werkzeug/0.11.3 Python/2.7.11
< Date: Wed, 13 Jan 2016 15:42:48 GMT
< 
* Closing connection 0
{"msg": "Access denied"}
```

Now, if I run my app with uwsgi + nginx I get

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)

> POST /api/get_predictions HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:8000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 964812
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------9ad7410b97d91f5d
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN
* Server nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Wed, 13 Jan 2016 15:45:48 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 24
< Connection: keep-alive
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Authentication Required"
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
<
```

curl keep running (or waiting for something?) and I don't get the `{"msg": "Access denied"}` message.

I noticed the `HTTP 1.0, assume close after body` in the development server response, and I guess it has something to do with that, but I don't know how to achieve the same behaviour with nginx.

Anybody can help?

The app is configured with

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myflaskapp**

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:<path to the socket>;
    }
}
```

and I left the default nginx config

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: I have just asked a related question in the nginx forum: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,277935